# CSS + jquery height

Tags: jquery, height

I want to make a div visible if the height of another div is 211px.

This is my script:

```
        if ( $(".posts-wrapper").height() == 211 ) { 
            $('.no-posts').css('display', 'block'); 
        }

        else {
            $('.no-posts').css('display', 'none'); 
        });
```

If you could tell me what I've done wrong, please.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you throw any javacript errors? Is jQuery getting loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `);` on the closing else.

```
    if ( $(".posts-wrapper").height() == 211 ) { 
        $('.no-posts').css('display', 'block'); 
    } else {
        $('.no-posts').css('display', 'none'); 
    }
```